# Arch Linux can't detect drives after update without reboot

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, usb, pacman, software-updates

After I do updates with `pacman -Syu`, I always have this annoying problem that I can't connect any new USB devices (External hard drive, USB to serial etc.) to my computer until I reboot.

The problem is that for example if I do updates in the morning without rebooting, then later in the day I connect a new device and forget that I did an update and waste time troubleshooting why it isn't working.

Is there a way to avoid having to restart? I don't even know if this is possible (maybe by somehow reloading the drivers?) or even a good idea.

If it isn't possible I am going to write a wrapper for `pacman` that automatically reboots afterwards.

Anyway, an explanation for why this happens is very much appreciated.

Comment: Your description is a bit vague. How do you know that the devices are not detected? Do you use `lsusb`? Do you check kernel messages? Normally, each time you connect a USB device, kernel messages should be generated which either report success or problems.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but having observed this behaviour myself I found discussions incriminating kernel updates. New kernel modules are loaded after the update while the previous kernel is still running. 
Kernel updates should be followed by a reboot on PCs, although [some may nuance this](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/mxil5e/comment/gvp1b17/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button).

Here's a 10+ yo [feature request](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/16702?project=1) that aims to alleviate the issue. You can see from the discussion that implementing it is not very easy.

I found the [kernel-modules-hook](https://github.com/saber-nyan/kernel-modules-hook) package which might help, but didn't test it myself. It would work better than an alias that auto reboots after any update.